# My clearScreen function doesn't clear the screen

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a game in CodeHS, but the clearScreen function doesn't clear the title screen, instead, it says that the "Sky" variable isn't defined, I assume it does the same for the rest of the variables. The title screen prints fine, I just can't clear it.

Any advice for shrinking the code is also appreciated, I tried making a function for making the windows but I have no idea how to.

Code:

```
var brown = new Color(140,74,47);
//The start function makes the title screen.
function start() {
    titleScreen();
    mouseClickMethod(clearScreen);
    }

function titleScreen() {
    //Landscape
var Sky = new Rectangle(400,500);
Sky.setPosition(0,0);
Sky.setColor(Color.blue);
add(Sky);
var Sun = new Circle(50);
Sun.setPosition(155,96);
Sun.setColor(Color.yellow);
add(Sun);
var Ground = new Rectangle(400,200);
Ground.setPosition(0,300);
Ground.setColor(Color.green);
add(Ground);
//Bulding
/*Windows go in order from left to right, top to bottom.
 *1 is the top left window.
 */
var Building = new Rectangle(100,300);
Building.setPosition(50,100);
Building.setColor(Color.grey);
add(Building);
var Window1 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window1.setPosition(60,110);
Window1.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window1);
var Window2 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window2.setPosition(105,110);
Window2.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window2);
var Window3 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window3.setPosition(60, 155);
Window3.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window3);
var Window4 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window4.setPosition(105,155);
Window4.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window4);
var Window5 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window5.setPosition(60,200);
Window5.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window5);
var Window6 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window6.setPosition(105,200);
Window6.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window6);
var Window7 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window7.setPosition(60,245);
Window7.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window7);
var Window8 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window8.setPosition(105,245);
Window8.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window8);
var Window9 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window9.setPosition(60,290);
Window9.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window9);
var Window10 = new Rectangle(35,35);
Window10.setPosition(105,290);
Window10.setColor(Color.white);
add(Window10);
var Door = new Rectangle(35,50);
Door.setPosition(83,350);
Door.setColor(brown);
add(Door);
var Title = new Text("Title", "100pt Aleo");
Title.setPosition(60,150);
Title.setColor(Color.black);
add(Title);
var Devs = new Text("By Terra", "40pt Aleo");
Devs.setPosition(75,200);
Devs.setColor(Color.black);
add(Devs);
var Play_Button_Background = new Rectangle(200,100);
Play_Button_Background.setPosition(90,350);
Play_Button_Background.setColor(Color.black);
add(Play_Button_Background);
var Play_Button_Text = new Text("Start", "40pt Aleo");
Play_Button_Text.setPosition(135,415);
Play_Button_Text.setColor(Color.white);
add(Play_Button_Text);
}

function clearScreen() {
    titleScreen();
    remove(Sky);
    remove(Sun);
    remove(Ground);
    remove(Building);
    remove(Window1);
    remove(Window2);
    remove(Window3);
    remove(Window4);
    remove(Window5);
    remove(Window6);
    remove(Window7);
    remove(Window8);
    remove(Window9);
    remove(Window10);
    remove(Door);
    remove(Title);
    remove(Devs);
    remove(Play_Button_Background);
    remove(Play_Button_Text);
}

function level1() {
    //Adds level 1.
    var test = new Circle(100);
    test.setPosition(100,100);
    add(test);
}
```

Comment: The only `Sky` in your code is scoped to the `titleScreen()` function, as far as `clearScreen()` knows, that variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll see if defining the variables works.